# php mysql array to string conversion error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

This is driving me crazy...

I'm simply trying to pull an INT value from my database (MySQL), but for some reason i get this error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\myjobs.php
>   on line 33

this points my html where I try to echo $deptnum:
`<h1><?php echo $deptnum; ?></h1>`

Here's some of my PHP code:

```
<?php

  require ("config.php");
  include ("menu.php"); 

  /* config.php CONTAINS CODE TO CONNECT TO DATABASE AND IT WORKS FINE */

  /* Check if a value for user_name exists */
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {

      $the_user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
       /* FYI, THIS DOES PULL THE CORRECT USERNAME, IN THIS CASE: "ussatjodo" */

      /* pull value from database */
      $result = $db->prepare("SELECT `dept` from `users` WHERE `username` = :uname");
      $result->execute(array(':uname' => $the_user_name));
      $deptnum=$result->fetch();


  } else {  
    $the_user_name = '';
  }

?>

<h1><?php echo $deptnum; ?></h1>
```

And here is the table "users"

[image]

**TO SUM IT UP:**

- $_SESSION['user_name'] correctly pulls a username (example: 'ussatjodo');
- All I'm trying to do is get the correct value for column 'dept' which in the case of username "ussatjodo", the 'dept' would be 1
- Currently the error is telling me there is an error that I'm trying to convert an array to string.

Comment: Just because your result only contains one field doesn't mean that `fetch()` will not return an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fetch()` returns an array indexed by the table column names.  Try:

```
echo $deptnum['dept'];
```

**PHP >= 5.4.0:**

```
$deptnum = $result->fetch()['dept'];
```

Comment: You would use a prepared statement and `bind_result()`.

Comment: Edited with another option.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment**. 
**Not relevant to the question**.

From what it looks like, you are storing passwords as plain text.

Rule of thumb, **NEVER STORE PLAIN TEXT PASSWORDS**

Always store encrypted passwords.
Use default encryption techniques ie http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php , available in PHP > 5.5

If you are using PHP < 5.5, https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat provides a compatibility library for using password_hash